# Getting 'Name servers refused query' on my domain when setting up Google cloud dns

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I'm trying to setup Google cloud DNS so I've created a new public managed zone which I'm planning to connect to a firebase project.

After creating the zones I got the 4 NS provided, to be used at the Registrar:

```
ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com
```

I've updated the NS at the registrar but it doesn't seem to be working.
When I query it with `https://dns.google.com/` I get this:

```
  {
  "Status": 2,
  "TC": false,
  "RD": true,
  "RA": true,
  "AD": false,
  "CD": false,
  "Question": [
    {
      "name": "[mydomain]",
      "type": 1
    }
  ],
    "Comment": "Name servers refused query (lame delegation?) [216.239.38.109, 216.239.32.109, 2001:4860:4802:36::6d, 216.239.36.109, 2001:4860:4802:32::6d, 2001:4860:4802:38::6d, 216.239.34.109, 2001:4860:4802:34::6d]."
}
```

I can't find anything else which I can try in the troubleshooting. Everything seems pretty straight forward - take NS and update the domain at the registrar, although I'm unsuccessful. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: What other DNS records did you create? Your name server is designated as the authoritative server for a domain name for which it does not have authoritative data.

Comment: That erros quite common while migrating from one DNS to another. Please, go to [the icann](https://lookup.icann.org/) and check your DNS status.

Comment: If on the ICANN page you can see the new NS, then you only need to wait. Also, you can request DNS cache cleanings at [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache) and [Cloudflare](https://1.1.1.1/purge-cache/) this may speed up the replication.

Comment: @ArmandoCuevas thanks Armando, I've tried ICANN but I have a country domain and I get the error TLD NOT SUPPORTED

Answer (score 3):

A lame delegation happens when one (or more) nameserver is asked about a domain and have the information, while other nameserver don't. Both nameserver must have the information, this is explained [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/troubleshooting-common-dns-misconfiguration-errors) in a better way and have some advices for troubleshooting, for example you could use the dig command or other [online tools](https://lookup.icann.org/) (as suggested on the comments) to retrieve your domain's DNS information. Here is another tool to check [DNS propagation](https://www.whatsmydns.net/).

Take into consideration that DNS changes could take a while until propagation is done, wait some hours and try again, if everything is properly configured on the registrar your domain should be up. Any further changes on Cloud DNS will take some time too, look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#propagation_of_changes) for more details.